# Assembly: no such 386 instruction

Tags: c, assembly

I am having trouble running my assembly code. This is my documented code. I wrote as much details as I know how to, so hopefully you can tell me how I a misunderstanding things.I am writing an assembly program that will be a callable function in `C`. The function prototype in `C` is the following:

`extern int count(char *string, char c)`

The assembly program is supposed to go through `string` and count how many instances of `c` are there. The assembly program is the following:

```
.text
.globl _count           # defining label _count with .globl for external reference

_count:
        pushl %ebp              # Create Stack frame
        movl %ebp, %esp

        xorl %eax, %eax         # Exclusive of eax register with itself to empty it
                                # Use of eax is proper as it is the accumulator for
                                # operands and results data

        movl 5(%ebp), %ecx      # Move parameters into temp register
        movl 6(%ebp), %edx

loop:
        compl $0, (%edx)        # Check if end of string char
        je end                  # Check for equality
        compl %ecx, (%edx)      # Check equality of character
        je Char                 # if equal to given char jump to char section
        addl $1, %edx           # Increment loop

Char:
        addl $1, $eax           # Add to the number of characters that are equal
        jmp loop                # Go back to loop

end:
        pop ebp                 # Reset the ebp register
        ret                     # Return value in eax
.end
```

I compile this way:

```
i386-as -o count.opc count.s
```

I am getting the following error:

```
count.s:19: Error: no such 386 instruction: `compl'
count.s:21: Error: no such 386 instruction: `compl'
count.s:26: Error: operands given don't match any known 386 instruction
```

So it is complaining about the `compl` instruction and I am not sure why since in another program it seems to recognize it, so it must be something with the logic of my program, at least I think. Although, how would I call this function inside `C`, do I need to compile both programs at the same time?
Thanks.

Comment: what 386 instruction do you think compl is? I cant find one

Comment: More than likely `cmpl`

Comment: May be you mean `cmpl`?

Comment: By the way, to compare characters you'll probably want `cmpb` instead.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman @pm100 I'm an idiot. it is cmpl that's all it was I spent hours on this. Any idead why it is complaining in the `Char` section where the code is `addl $1, $eax` it is giving me an error `operands given don't match any known 386 instruction`.

Comment: Okay but `cmpl` is not the only problem.

Comment: `%eax` not `$eax`. They haven't got the spellchecker instruction working yet. :)

Comment: @FrankKotler thanks, do you see anything else wrong in there?

Comment: The argument addresses (5+ebp and 6+ebp) are also incorrect: They should be 8+ebp and 12+ebp. The second "compl" instruction (actually cmpl) should be "cmp %cl, (%edx)" because you compare bytes only. The "je Char" instruction will cause an endless loop when the first character is found while %eax is incremented for ANY character in the string...

Comment: @MartinRosenau why are the addresses 8+ebp and 12+ebp? is char just 1 byte? So why are you giving it four bytes of memory?

Comment: @TryingHard: I assume the function is a "cdecl"-style function as it is typically called from C code. In this case each parameter is put on the stack using a "push" instruction. In 32-bit mode you cannot push 8 or 16 bits on the stack so even 8- and 16-bit arguments will be written to the low bits of a register (such as AL or AX) and the entire register (such as EAX) will be pushed. This is why each argument requires 32 bits on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

No compl that I can see, just many cmpl

`http://www.fermimn.gov.it/linux/quarta/x86/cmp.htm`